# Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009, Problem email attachment

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

In NAV 2009 when I try to send a quote my quote goes to attachment, not the email body. When I click Print then preview>>>file>>>send >>>Report by Email I see the quote in the email attachment but I want to the quote in the email body. How do I do this?